# Cómo imprimir desde javascript a html el contenido de un array con varios valores anidados?

Tags: javascript

Estoy con javascript necesitando imprimir en un (li) de un archivo html el contenido anidado de un array,, pero cuando lo quiero imprimir en la web me aparece este error: [object Object], entiendo que hace esto porque no definí cuales son los valores que quiero imprimir. imagino que debo hacer algun (var i=0; i

```
array= [
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB"
    },
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB"
    },]

/*Esta funcion está ligada a un onClick del html*/

function agregarElementos(){ 

var lista=document.getElementById("ulListado");  /*Reconoce el elemento html utilizado*/

                            var linew= document.createElement("li");        /*Crea otro elemento dentro del elemento contenedor*/

                            var contenido = document.createTextNode(array[0]);  /*Imprime algo dentro del elemento 'li' "*/

                            lista.appendChild(linew);

                            linew.appendChild(contenido);}
```

Comment: Esas soluciones antiguas basadas en appendChild deberian eliminarlas, con JQuery append() y empty() todo es mucho más facil y rápido

Comment: @DrakonWeb `appendChild` es el estándar JavaScript, mientras que `append` de jQuery es parte de una biblioteca que usa `appendChild` en su implementación. Puede ser más fácil (jQuery no deja de ser una biblioteca para simplificar el uso de JavaScript), pero no es más rápido porque se están realizando más operaciones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes imprimir un objeto o array en texto, usando el método [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/JSON/stringify)

```js
var obj = {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB"
    }
    
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(obj)
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Necesitas crear una función de loop para acceder a los valores del array, dentro si necesitas navegar entre las propiedades de cada objeto.

Similar a este código.

```js
var myArray = [
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB"
    },
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB"
    }]
var foo = myArray.map(function(bar){
  return '<li>'+bar.marca+' '+bar.modelo+'</li>'
})
document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML = foo;
```

```html
<div id='foo'></div>
```

Comment: Funciona a la perfección esta forma pero tengo una consulta. Yo estoy queriendo hace algo parecido al amigo de acá y cuando despliego me aparece una coma entre cada cadena de caracteres, alguien sabe por que? y como la quito?. Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: En mi caso yo cada vez que hago click en una imagen (que representa a un producto) se despliegan en un costado su nombre y el precio. Ahora, si hago click en otra imagen (otro producto), también se despliega pero entre ambos productos me aparece la coma a la que me refería en el comentario anterior.

Answer (score 2):

Para evitar que salga la coma, se puede imprimir con un for:

```js
function agregarElementos(){

  var text = "";
  let array=[
   {
    marca: "Moitorola",
    modelo: "G 84 PLAY",
   },
   {
    marca: "Samgun",
    modelo: "G 84 PLAY",
   },
   {
    marca: "Huawei",
    modelo: "G 84 PLAY",
   }];     

        for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            text += '<li>'+array[i].marca + " " +array[i].modelo+'</li>';
        }
        
     document.getElementById("ulListado").innerHTML = text;   
}

agregarElementos();
```

```html
<ul id="ulListado"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

simplemente te falta iterar con `array.forEach`

```js
array= [
    {
        "marca": "Moitorola",
        "modelo": "G 84 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB"
    },
    {
        "marca": "Motorola",
        "modelo": "G 4 PLAY",
        "sistema_operativo": "Android",
        "pantalla_pulgadas": 5,
        "pantalla_resolucion": "1280x720",
        "camara_resolucion": "8 Mpx",
        "camara_frontal": true,
        "camara_frontal_res": "5 Mpx",
        "memoria_interna": "16 GB"
    },]

function agregarElementos(){ 
var lista=document.getElementById("ulListado"); 
array.forEach(function(data,index){
var linew= document.createElement("li");    
var contenido = document.createTextNode(data.marca+' '+data.modelo+" "+data.sistema_operativo+" "+data.pantalla_pulgadas+" "+data.pantalla_resolucion+" "+data.camara_resolucion);
lista.appendChild(linew);
linew.appendChild(contenido);

})
}
agregarElementos();
```

```html
<div id="ulListado"></div>
```

Comment: Realmente han funcionado todos los códigos que me pasaron, y este también funciona excelente, sin embargo si quiero sólo mostar un elemento sólo dentroi del array cómo hago? intenté cambiar a: array[1].forEach(function(data,index)    para elegir el segundo elemento del array y no me funciona.